# How do I place the close button of a fixed modal in a fixed position?

Tags: css, modal-dialog, css-position

I have created a modal window with fixed position elements, which have editable elements. I want to pin the modal window's close button to the top right of the modal window.

```css
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  background: #ffa01f;
}

.close_modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.textarea {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: palegreen;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="close_modal">
    <button type="button">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="textarea" contenteditable></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, the close button is not fixed because it is in the absolute position:

```css
.modal-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden scroll;
  background: #ffa01f;
}

.close_modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.outer {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.textarea {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 100px;
  background: palegreen;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-container">
  <div class="close_modal">
    <button type="button">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="textarea" contenteditable>texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext
        texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext
        texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext
        texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttext
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, in the fixed position, the scroll bar and Close button overlap. Can I solve this problem with a stylesheet without changing the document?

I don't want to set a fixed interval of several px because the width of the scroll bar is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can move it in a bit from the right and the top.

```
.close_modal {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```